# Bound string value from ViewModel not updating in UI element

Tags: xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have this `TextBlock` in XAML that its text property is bound to a viewmodel command.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}"></TextBlock>
```

Meanwhile, the viewmodel looks like this:

```
\\ the text property
private string _someText = "";

public const string SomeTextPropertyName = "SomeText";
public string SomeText
{
    get
    {
        return _someText;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(SomeTextPropertyName, ref _someText, value);
    }
}

\\ the command that changes the string

private RelayCommand<string> _theCommand;

public RelayCommand<string> TheCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _theCommand
            ?? (_theCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(ExecuteTheCommand));
    }
}

private void ExecuteTheCommand(string somestring)
{
    _someText = "Please Change";
    \\ MessageBox.Show(SomeText);
}
```

I can successfully call the `TheCommand` as I did able to call a `MessageBox` using that command from the triggering element. The `SomeText` value also change as shown in the commented `MessageBox` line. What am I doing wrong here, is there any silly mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the field `_someText` directly, which means you're by-passing the setter of the `SomeText` property. But that setter is calling the  `Set(SomeTextPropertyName, ref _someText, value);` method that is internally raising the `PropertyChanged` event.

That `PropertyChanged` event is necessary for the Data Binding, so that it knows the `SomeText` property was updated.

That means, instead of doing this:

```
private void ExecuteTheCommand(string somestring)
{
    _someText = "Please Change";
    \\ MessageBox.Show(SomeText);
}
```

Just do this and it should work:

```
private void ExecuteTheCommand(string somestring)
{
    SomeText = "Please Change";
    \\ MessageBox.Show(SomeText);
}
```